# editorfor send value to template asp.net-mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I have a view that has a string variable and an editorfor. I'd like to send the string variable to the editorFor template partial view

```
//parent view
string message = "message";
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.someObject)


//editor template 
@model someObject
var message = messageFromParentView;
<div>@message</div>

//other inputs for someObject
```

how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ViewBag` to do this. Set property on parent view or controller and access it inside editor template code.

**Parent View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Message= "message";
}
```

**Editor Template**

```
<div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
```

Comment: so the viewbag will have to come from the controller right? I can't do this just from inside the view?

Comment: `ViewBag` is always there, you could do it inside the view.

Comment: an example would be great

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad: Added example